# c# asp.net sql server web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My application is not able to pick connection string from **web.config** file:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Web.config File

Regards,
Praveen N

Comment: How can anyone help you if you don't post your web.config?

Comment: share the web.config and code ?

Comment: Sorry Kumar and user3373870, Here is my web.config file <connectionStrings>
      <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=XYZ;database=nDatabase;uid=sa;password=sa1234;" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Always remember that application layer configuration file always override the DAL layer configuration file. so always put connection string on application layer configuration file when you run the application.

Thanks
Deepak Joshi

Comment: As I am new to this new Portal unfortunately i am still short of points to vote up for your answer. Other wise I would have voted 5+ :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a database in your localhost, you have to declare your connection string as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBName" connectionString="Data Source=(Your Data Source);Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The data source is the data server to which you project is connected. 
If you want a more precise answer then kindly post your code and requirements.

Comment: When I try to debug the compiler is not looking into web.config of DAL layer its straight a way jumping to UI layer web.config bit surprising .

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

To read the connection string into your code, use the `ConfigurationManager` class:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```